# Handmade reusable HTML component | conflit with Thymeleaf syntax

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing a reusable HTML component following [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-reusable-html-components-without-component-based-frameworks/) guide.

I have tested the guide with some sample code from bootstrap and it worked properly.
Now I am trying to use it for my navbar, which uses Thymeleaf syntax and I think it is giving conflicts due to the fact that both use single quotes.

Here is what I mean:

```
class Header extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = ` ***a single quote to open ***
      <nav>            
        {*Header code goes here *}         
      </nav>
    `; *** a single quote to close
  }
}
```

Some code from my navbar, where in the srcset and src attribute single quotes are used:

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container">
                <span class="navbar-brand">
                  <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                      <img
                        th:attr="srcset=|
                            @{${cloudinaryBaseUrl} + ${cloudinaryTransfCommon} + 'w_256/XXX.jpg'} 256w,
                            @{${cloudinaryBaseUrl} + ${cloudinaryTransfCommon} + 'w_1280//XXX.jpg'} 1280w|"
                        th:src="@{${cloudinaryBaseUrl} + ${cloudinaryTransfCommon} + 'w_auto' + '/XXX.jpg'}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="70" alt="logo"
                      />
                  </a>
                </span>
```

If my intuition about the problem is correct, how can I overcome it?

===========================================================

**UPDATE**: I have tried isolating the problem, and found out that this line works:

```
th:src="@{https://theUrl}"
```

But this one doesn't:

```
th:src="@{${cloudinaryBaseUrl} + ${cloudinaryTransfCommon} + 'w_auto' + '/XXX.jpg'}"
```

So I believe the single quotes may be indeed the problem

Comment: That looks like a backtick instead of a single quote. Check and fix eventually

Comment: You're right, then my intuition must be wrong. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: What is the actual error/"conflict"?

Comment: The component simply isn't shown. BTW, i have just done a few tests and I know for sure the problem is related to syntax in both src and srcset. I am going give more details in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different things happening here - but the bottom line is: The reason it is not working as expected is because of the way the code mixes Thymeleaf variables with JavaScript code.

**Simple HTML Example**

Consider this very simple piece of Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:text="${cloudinaryBaseUrl} + 'hello'"></div>
```

And assume that the value we pass to the Thymeleaf renderer for `cloudinaryBaseUrl` is `/foo/bar/baz/`.

If we place this in the HTML body, then the result will be the following HTML:

```
<div>/foo/bar/baz/hello</div>
```

So far, so good.

**Adding JavaScript to the Mix**

But in your case, you are embedding your HTML inside a JavaScript script - it's no longer a piece of HTML that will be rendered by Thymeleaf (on the server!). Now it is a string of text that will be processed by JavaScript (in the browser!), long after Thymeleaf has finished its work.

You have this:

```
<script>
  class Header extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `
        <div th:text="${cloudinaryBaseUrl} + 'hello'"></div>
      `;
    }
  };

  customElements.define('main-header', Header);
</script>
```

The text inside the backticks is a [JavaScript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - which just happens to also use `${...}` for inserting values into text - but completely unrelated to Thymeleaf's `${...}` syntax.

This will fail.

JavaScript will not be able to substitute any correct value into `${cloudinaryBaseUrl}`. You may get something rendered - or you may get a JS error. Depends on the specific template literal being used.

**Passing Thymeleaf Variables to JavaScript**

If you want to pass Thymeleaf variables to JavaScript, you can [do it like this](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining):

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
            
var baseUrl = [[${cloudinaryBaseUrl}]];

class Header extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
        <div>${baseUrl}hello</div>
    `;
  }
};

customElements.define('main-header', Header);

</script>
```

Note the `th:inline="javascript"` added to the script tag, and the use of `[[...]]`.

By the time it reaches the browser, Thymeleaf has updated the JavaScript code to be this:

```
var baseUrl = '/foo/bar/baz/';
...
```

So, now the JS will generate this HTML:

```
<main-header>
    <div>/foo/bar/baz/hello</div>
</main-header>
```

**A Better Way - Use Thymeleaf Fragments**

If you are doing this as an exercise, then this is how you can combine your JavaScript template fragments with Thymeleaf variables.

But Thymeleaf has support for fragments *built into the Thymeleaf language*. So, there is no real need for any of that JavaScript.

Take a look here: [Template Layouts](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#template-layout).

This does exactly the same thing as your JavaScript approach - but with full Thymeleaf support and no need to pass variables to JavaScript.

Comment: Awesome explanation Andrew! I can't thank you enough!
I am now diving into Thymleaf Fragments, but for the sake of learning I tried the first approach (using javascript to create reusable components): it is working! The component is shown properly, except for the image. I guess something may be off with its specific syntax. Do you happen to see what could be the problem?

th:src="@{${baseUrl} +  ' v160XXX/nameXXX/XXX.png ' } "

Comment: For the image, the first thing to check is if you can display the image using the URL: Open a browser and manually type in the full URL into the address bar: `http://your_base_url.com:8080/myapp/v160XXX/nameXXX/XXX.png` - or whatever the values need to be... The image file needs to be in a publicly accessible directory (usually called `resources/public/images`). If it is accessible, you will see it in your web page. Then, make sure your Thymeleaf is generating the same URL. If you cannot access the image file manually, then there is some other configuration problem in your web application.